# Run in an entire Specflow scenario with a Specflow line?

Tags: c#, automation, cucumber, specflow

I have a Specflow scenario that runs through a wizard in our application and creates a form, much like a user would. Let's call this Scenario A.

Now, I need to create another scenario that takes the created form and fills it out/submits it. Let's call this Scenario B.

To be able to run Scenario B, I need Scenario A to run first. Is there a way to run the entire Scenario A with the `Background` keyword in Scenario B? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call steps form other steps, so you the way to do what you want is to create a step which calls all the steps, including those in the background:

```
Backgroud:
   Given I have done this

Scenario:
   Given another thing
   And this other thing
```

then you can create a step like this

```
[Binding]
public class MySteps: Steps //<- this is important if you want to reuse steps
{

    Given("I have done eveything")]
    public void GiveIHaveDoneEverything()
    {
        Given("I have done this");
        Given("another thing");
        Given("this other thing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Calling steps within steps is bad practice for Cucumber-based frameworks. Instead, make helper functions: `iHaveDoneThis(); anotherThing(); thisOtherThing();`

Comment: @KyleFairns can you expand on why you consider this bad practice? Not that I'm against helper functions per se, but I'm unsure why its bad practice

Comment: Problems are hard to track down and it actually makes maintenance harder. Instead, use helper methods.

Check out [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cukes/Zi5IIAr4dJg/S9A0cnNc0G4J), it'll explain it more. 

In practice, you won't have any errors by doing things like this, but when it comes round to a step within a step within a step within a step (etc) failing - you have to go down the rabbit hole to find out why exactly it failed. Creating helper functions can make code more maintainable.